# Using custom display template for enum value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC 3 application I am developing I have an enumeration and custom display template for it.

In one of the views I need to display specific enum value, but when I write code like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => EnumType.EnumValue)
```

I recieve compilation error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I can think of solution to add property to my model with appropriate value, but maybe there is easier approach to leverage my display template in such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom editor and display templates for types by naming the template for the type.

Information on how templates are identified: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

For Razor replace `<%@ Control ...` with `@model TemplateType`.

Comment: Yes, I have done so. Question is how to use it if I want to display not the Model property by enumeration value (constant). Like, for example @Html.DisplayFor(model => DayOfWeek.Sunday), if I have defined display template for DayOfWeek enum.

Comment: @user727030: Sorry, missed the bit about static result. The expression passed to `DisplayFor` is not evaluated but specific `Expression` sub-types are used to identify the property or field selected. Have you considered using it as a partial view?